# Parsley.js Override Default Type Mapping

Tags: parsley.js

I have a series of fields where they need to be validated as a number, not as an integer. I've tried a number of different methods to change the constraint from integer to number, but none seem to stick.  I've resorted to modifying the parsley.js source to map type="number" to the number validator, not the integer validator. There has to be another way other than modifying the library source code. The fields need to be type="number" to ensure the numeric keyboard is default, but they are NOT integers, but numbers with decimals.

Below is an example field

```
<input type="number" id="intimes-hobbs" data-parsley-type="number" value="" placeholder="Hobbs" required>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/508) and why it happens that way. I agree that there should be a way to handle this case.